# how to replace tab with image (similar to navbar-brand) in vue bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

```
<b-tabs>
    <b-tab active>
      <template v-slot:title>
         <b-img src="../assets/logo_big.png"></b-img> I'm <i>custom</i> <strong>title</strong>
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab contents 1</p>
    </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

doesn't work. i don't want to use navbar because i don't want the page to update the url. I was thinking of making a invisible b-tab and putting a clickable image on top however i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Using a `<b-img>` seems to work fine: https://codeply.com/p/WbdxpIBpVM

Comment: you can also make a slot and insert there (not sure what styling would look like)

Comment: Does it work if you use a normal `<img>` instead of `<b-img>`?

Comment: Its in their doc. `<b-tab active>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <b-spinner type="grow" small></b-spinner> I'm <i>custom</i> <strong>title</strong>
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab contents 1</p>
    </b-tab>`  Use template for custom tab header